# Java regex string cannot start with 2 specific strings or be exactly a 3rd string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a Java regex that will **not** match a string that:

- starts with `rc-`
- starts with `env-`
- is exactly `master`

So the results should be:

```
Not a match: `master`
Not a match: `rc-blah`
Not a match: `env-demo`
Not a match: `rc-1.2.34`
Is a match:  `something`
Is a match:  `issuance-fix`
Is a match:  `something-env-blah`
Is a match:  `master-something`
Is a match:  `yes-rc-12.43.56`
```

Currently I've got `^(?!master|rc-|env-).*$` which is essentially a "doesn't start with" expression. This mostly works but `master-something` is flagged as a non-match.

I've tried this: `^((?!rc-|env-).*|(?!master))$` which incorrectly flags `master` as a match.

I've tried various other combinations but I can't seem to get the results I want.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `^(?!master$|rc-|env-).*$`. See the linked post and scroll to *`a string starting with a specific pattern`* and *`a string equal to some string`*

Comment: Blimey that was fast!! Thanks, works perfectly! Post as an answer and I'll accept it.